# android how to get elapsed days and hours from pre-stored timestamp?

Tags: android

how can i get a clock-independent timestamp to count elapsed days and hours from specific timestamp ?
below methods do not work :

```
system.currenttimemillis //doesn't work it changes when wall clock gets changed
system.nanotime   //maybe better choice than above one .maybe work(correct?) 
system.elapsedrealtime //not works,if user boots up the phone
```

also i dont want to use NTP

Comment: you can store the information from your previous time stamp then just get a new time stamp for the current time, retrieve your stored data, then just subtract the days, hours, etc from both of them to get the time elapsed

Comment: This approach is susceptible to user changing the date/time on the device, thus is not acceptabe by OP.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Android supports what you want - your use case seems to beg for NTP.

Also I do not think `System.nanoTime()` would work because(taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html)):

> uptimeMillis() is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted. **This clock stops when the system enters deep sleep** (CPU off, display dark, device waiting for external input), but is not affected by clock scaling, idle, or other power saving mechanisms. **This is the basis for** most interval timing such as Thread.sleep(millls), Object.wait(millis), and **System.nanoTime()**.`